# При поиске возникает ошибка Too many request

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

При поиске по таблице она изменяется после каждого введённого символа, используется связка Laravel + Vue.js. На ларавель используем paginate(20). При активном использовании поиска через некоторое время появляется ошибка  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
onSearchChange(event){
        this.searchQuery = event.target.value
        if(event.target.value)
        {
            axios.post('/api/technique/all/search?page=' + this.currentPage, {
                searchQuery: this.searchQuery
            })
                .then(res => {
                    if (res.status === 200) {
                        this.tableData = res.data.data
                        this.totalItems = res.data.total
                    }
                })
        }
        else{
            this.getAllTableData()
        }
    },
    getAllTableData(){
        axios.get('/api/technique/all?page=' + this.currentPage, {
            headers: {
                "Content-type": "application/json"
            }
        })
            .then(res => {
                if (res.status === 200) {
                    if (res.data.length !== 0) {
                        this.tableData = res.data.data
                        this.totalItems = res.data.total
                        this.loaded = true
                    }
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение с помощью debounce от библиотеки lodash: откладываю вызов функции поиска на 500мс, что уменьшает количество axios запросов при вводе в поле поиска. Но всё равно ищу альтернативы

Comment: В строке поиска надо с перва дать минимальную длину текста. Потом сделать запрос. И второе, если я правильно понял, вы точно сделали. после отпускания клавиши надо дать паузу, может кто то медленно пишет )))